# No overload matches this call. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'test' does not exist in type 'UserConfigExport'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, vitest

I'm trying to set up vitest on my Vite/React/TS project, and it's not working properly,I looked at some of the solutions I found online, but none worked.

My ultimate goal is to make this file work:

```
import ErrorMessage from "./ErrorMessage";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";


it("should have hello world", () => {
  render(<ErrorMessage />);
  const message = screen.queryByText(/Hello World/i);

  expect(message).toBeVisible();
});
```

currently this gives the following error:

```
Property 'toBeVisible' does not exist on type 'Assertion<HTMLElement | null>'.ts(2339)
```

I found a tutorial online that makes this work, but when I try it this is what I get.

vite.config.ts

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    css: true,
    setupFiles: "./src/tests/setup",
  },
});
```

to get the `toBeVisisible()` on my test file, I need to set css to true, but the test property here is what is giving the error, a common solution you'll find online is to import the defineConfig from `"vitest/config"`, and though it's true this does fix the error above, it'll cause another error for the `plugins` property, `No overload matches this call.` on the `[react()]`.

Another solution I found was to create two files:

a `vite.config.ts` that exports the `defineConfig` with the react plugin, and a `vitest.config.ts` that export the `defineConfig` with the test property.

vitest.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    css: true,
    setupFiles: "./src/tests/setup",
  },
});
```

This doesn't solve the problem, a possible reason why is because it's not running my setupFiles properly, (I have a setup file in the appropriate directory"

for now, this is all I have in the setup.js

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
```

and technically I can just import the above on my test file, but I still want the setup file to run because I'll be doing other stuff in it.

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "types": ["vitest/globals"]
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

tsconfig.node.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts", "vitest.config.ts"]
}
```

Please let me know if there is something I should add.